# How to check if a Shared Preference is set in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean, sharedpreferences

Coming from java android am finding it hard to implement some of my methods that I was used to in android. One if that of checking a Boolean shared preference.

```
SharedPreferences prefget = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if (!prefget.getBoolean("user_signedin", false)) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, Signin.class));
}
```

In dart I have tried this:

```
isUserLoggedin() async {
    SharedPreferences appPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (!appPrefs.getBool("user_signedin")) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Signin()));
    }
}
```

and the error that i get is:

> Exception has occurred.
>   _AssertionError (Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null)

I have also tried to rewrite my code using logical comparison but still the same result:

```
isUserLoggedin() async {
    SharedPreferences appPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    bool userSignedin = appPrefs.getBool("user_signedin") ? appPrefs.getBool("user_signedin") : false;

    if (userSignedin) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Signin()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Before checking for true or false, you should possibly check if the value you are trying to retrieve is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use ?? to set a value if it's null, then you can use a similar logic as you did on android

```
isUserLoggedin() async {
    SharedPreferences appPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (!(appPrefs.getBool("user_signedin") ?? false)) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Signin()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The get function can return null and null cannot be used in if statements.
You can use the ?? operator, which runs the right side when the left side is null.

```
bool userSignedin = appPrefs.getBool("user_signedin") ?? false
if (!userSignedin) {
    Navigator....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You encountered that error because the above given checks the null value instead of bool:

```dart
// even if you are using 'getBool', it returns null
// so you are checking: if(!null) ---ERROR: boolean expression must not be null
if (!appPrefs.getBool("user_signedin")){...}
```

And you fixed it with same logic so you are getting same error:

```dart
// This appPrefs.getBool("user_signedin") returns null
// so you are checking:
// bool userSignedin = null ? ... : ...;
// Again condition is null
bool userSignedin = appPrefs.getBool("user_signedin") ? appPrefs.getBool("user_signedin") : false;
```

solution is to use null-aware operator in dart

```dart
bool userSignedin = appPrefs.getBool("user_signedin") ?? false; 

// this is saying:
// if this 'appPrefs.getBool("user_signedin")' 
// returns a Boolean value then return it,
// but if null return a false to be the default value.
```